# Grouping county level data into states with R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to learn R by using the John's Hopkins COVID-19 data located at:

https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series

I'm trying to work with the time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv file. The data is in a time series format with resolution down to county level. I'd like to work with state level totals for each day. I'm able to remove the columns of info I don't need, but get stuck trying to group the counties into states.

Comment: Which files are you using?  Both time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv and time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv have a column called `Province_State` that lists the state.

Comment: I'm using the time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv file

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/covid19.analytics/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with `dplyr`. We can use the `RCurl` library to download the data easily.

```
library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv"
raw <- getURL(url)
data <- read.csv(text=raw)
data %>%
   group_by(Province_State) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(ends_with("20")), sum)
## A tibble: 58 x 78
#   Province_State X1.22.20 X1.23.20 X1.24.20 X1.25.20 X1.26.20 X1.27.20 X1.28.20 X1.29.20 X1.30.20 X1.31.20 X2.1.20 X2.2.20 X2.3.20 X2.4.20
#   <fct>             <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
# 1 Alabama               0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0
# 2 Alaska                0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0
# 3 American Samoa        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0
# 4 Arizona               0        0        0        0        1        1        1        1        1        1       1       1       1       1
# 5 Arkansas              0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0
# 6 California            0        0        0        0        2        2        2        2        2        3       3       3       6       6
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`: 1 line to read text, 1 to make the mean by group:

```r
library(data.table)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv"

dt <- fread(url)

dt[, lapply(.SD, sum),
   by  = "Province_State", .SDcols = colnames(dt)[endsWith(suffix = "20", colnames(dt))]]
```